# Android Service TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, text-to-speech

Hello I working on an app that readout the incoming message using service, it works fine but changing the TextToSpeech speed and pitch on service activity wont work. I used intent to get the speed and pitch value from MainActivity which works, but setting the speed and pitch to TTS wont work it remains on same speed and pitch value. I'm happy to receive any suggestions. Thanks

Speaker.java

```
public class Speaker extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech tts;
private boolean ready = false;
private boolean allowed = false;
float speed, pitch;
public Speaker() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    speed = (float) intent.getExtras().get("Speed");
    pitch = (float) intent.getExtras().get("Pitch");
    Log.i("Speed", String.valueOf(speed));
    Log.i("Pitch", String.valueOf(pitch));
    return START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public Speaker(Context context){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        tts.setPitch(pitch);
        tts.setSpeechRate(speed);
        ready = true;
    }else{
        ready = false;
    }
}

public void speak(String text){
      tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}

public void pause(int duration){
    tts.playSilence(duration, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}
public void destroy(){
    tts.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: maybe onInit is executing before onStartCommand does?  Have you also verified that the logs inside onStartCommand are giving you the expected values?  Have you verified that whatever speech engine you are using supports the speed and pitch commands by testing in a simpler activity (ie not a service)?

Comment: I already tried by placing the values for speed and pitch in onInit. I logged the values it works fine